# SQL: select average of varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, average, varchar

I would like to make a report that will show the average grade for different tasks.

I am having trouble with how to get the averages. I need to figure out how to convert the grades to floats so that I can take the averages. The grades sometimes have non-numeric or null values, although most values look like "2.0" or "3.5". I can exclude anything that is non-numeric.

This is what I have so far:

```
Select
GradingScores.task As task,
Avg(Cast((SELECT GradingScores.score WHERE GradingScores.score LIKE '%[^0-9]%')As float)) As averages
From
GradingScores
```

I am using FlySpeed SQL Query.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? `'%[^0-9]%'` is not a correct wildcard expression in (standard) SQL

Comment: It is valid for SQL server, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using [IsNumeric](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx)

```
Select
GradingScores.task As task,
Avg(Cast(GradingScores.score as float) As averages
From
GradingScores where IsNumeric(GradingScores.score) = 1
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. The only problem I have now is how to show the average for the tasks 'responsibility' and 'collaboration'. The problem is that the data isn't clean and I can't change the data.. For example, my results look like:   "Responsibility", 3.0  "Responsibility in Guitar", 4.0 "Responsibility in Math", 3.4 "Collaboration in Math" 2.4, "Collaboration in Music", 3.0. I need an average of all of the responsibility grades and all of the collaboration grades, so I should just get two results.

Answer (score 1):

Just simply convert() and use isnumeric() function in T-SQL

```
select avg(convert(float,score))
from GradingScores 
where isnumeric(score)=1
```

Answer (score 0):

here's what worked for me:

```
SELECT AVG(CAST(columnName AS FLOAT)) FROM tableName;
```